# Extract data from a sheet that changes name every month

Tags: excel, vba, url, worksheet

I download a file every month. I extract data from one of its sheet and paste in to another file. I am automating this whole process - the only problem is that its sheet changes name every month, but it only changes from 1703 to 1704 to 1705 etc. I have identified this change with the following code:

```
        Dim newDate: newDate = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "YYMM")
```

and the name of both the sheet and workbook I download is going to be :

```
        filename = "BSR" & "_" & newDate & ".xlsx"
```

How can I go about putting this in a copy paste code. I.e:

```
        wbsecond.Sheets("filename").Range("A1:AD1105").Copy _
        Destination:=wbfirst.Sheets("FX").Range("A1")
```

The whole code is below:

```
        Sub fx()

        Dim filename As String
        Dim newDate: newDate = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "YYMM")
        Dim wbfirst As Workbook
        Dim wbsecond As Workbook

        Dim staticFolder As String
        Dim dateformat As String


        'location of the parent folder
        staticFolder = "\C:abnsd\location\sublocation\test\"

        'provides previous month YYYYMM

        dateformat = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Date), "yyyymm", 1)

        'workbook with the code
        Set wbfirst = ThisWorkbook

        filename = "BSR" & "_" & newDate & ".xlsx"

        Workbooks.Open "https://fakeurl.com/site0266/FX/Global%20FX%20Rates/" & filename

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs staticFolder & "\" & dateformat & "\" & "Source files" & "\" & "FX" & " - " & dateformat & ".xlsx"


        Stop



    'workbook that needs to be copied over from
    Set wbsecond = Application.Workbooks.Open(staticFolder & "\" & dateformat & "\" & "Source files" & "\" & "FX" & " - " & dateformat & ".xlsx", _
        UpdateLinks:=0)


    wbsecond.Sheets("filename").Range("A1:AD1105").Copy _
    Destination:=wbfirst.Sheets("FX").Range("A1")

    wbsecond.Close savechanges:=False

    MsgBox "You have successfully transferred the FX File of " & dateformat


        End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please include a question?

Comment: Wouldn't you just need `wbsecond.Sheets(filename).Range("A1:AD1105").Copy`? (removed the quotes around "filename", which was making it a string, not using the variable.